# Python Connect 4. Check for diagonal winner

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am writing a connect 4 game in python and am unsure where to start when implementing a check diagonal function. It is a 7 by 6 grid. So far I've got horizontal and vertical.

```
#checks for a winner
def check_winner(self):
    winner = (self.check_hori()) or self.check_vert())
    return winner

#checks for winner horizontally
def check_hori(self):
    row=''
    for x in range(7):
        for y in range(6):
            row += self.__board[x][y]

        #R=Red, B=Blue
        if 'RRRR' or 'BBBB' in row:
            return True

    #False if no winner is detected
        row=''
    return False

#checks for a vertical winner
def check_vert(self):
    col=''
    for y in range(6):
        for x in range(7):
            col += self.__board[x][y]

        if 'RRRR' or 'BBBB' in col:
            return True

    #False if no winner is detected
        col=''
    return False
```

I am aware that it is possible to get it to check each possible combination but this would require many lines of code and I am sure they will be a simpler way.
Thanks